# VS Code: Relative Import - No module named x

Tags: python

I know this is yet another question about "No module named x". But I've tried everything I could find from stackoverflow (and also the internet) but it's still not working for me.

Steps I create a project:

1. Create a project named `my_project` then `cd my_project`
2. Create a virtual environment `python -m venv .env` and open a VS Code workspace with this folder
3. This is my folder structure

```
my_project
├── __init__.py
├── folder_1
│   ├── file_1.py
│   └── folder_2
│       └── file_2.py -- this is where the function my_function is written
```

However, in `file_1.py` when I try to import a function in `folder_2/file_2.py` as below

```py
# file_1.py

from folder_1.folder_2.file_2 import my_function
```

Then I bump into the following issue:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1'
```

Hope someone can help.

UPDATE: CSBigSur is correct. In my case, it's just a problem with [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)

Comment: `from folder_2.file_2 import my_function` should do it.

Comment: if I do `from folder_2.file_2 import my_function`, `pylance` will tell me `Import "folder_2.file_2" could not be resolved`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import folder2.file2 as f2
# your code
f2.your_func()
```

***or***

```
from folder2.file2 import your_func
# your code
your_func()
```